# Rewrite all URLs except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that's moved to a new home. I'd like to redirect all of that site's URLs (domain.com/*) to domain.com/index.php *except* domain.com/image.png. Can anybody suggest a mod_rewrite rule that would rewrite all URLs except the URL for the image file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image.png$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```